# How to get all props in child component by utility function?

Tags: reactjs

### Problem

I'm not sure how to get all props from destructured object.
I know If I don't use destructured object, I could get them easily, but in this case need to use it.
I also need to utility function which can use in other components

### Code

Parent component

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import House from "./House";

const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (count === 2) return;
    setTimeout(() => {
      setCount(count + 1);
    }, 1000);
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <House count={count} text={text} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Child component

```js
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
const House = ({ count, text }) => {
  const ref = useRef(count);

  console.log(this); // window object or undefined in strict mode

  useEffect(() => {
    // need to get all props by utility function

    console.log(ref.current);
    ref.current = count;
  });

  return <div className="App">{count}</div>;
};

export default House;
```

There would be better alternative way maybe?

Comment: const House = ({ count, text }).
you are not getting value for count and text in your house component which is passed in App function ???

Comment: I can get them, but I need utility function which can get all arguments from destructured object

Comment: You can't if you're destructuring your object. What is the reason you _have_ to use destructuring?

Comment: If you can change the parameter definition then you can do `{count, text, ...r}`, then to log all props you would do `console.log({count, text, ...r})` which would resemble your props object

Comment: @NickParsons 
Im trying to create kind of tiny library of why-did-you-render by myself, so I need to implement utility function which can get all props .
Or if somebody has alternative way, just let me know please. Maybe Im trying to implement in wrong way

Comment: If you have a regular `function` instead of an arrow function you technically could use `arguments`, but that feels a bit clunky imo. Maybe creating a HOC would be better for what you’re trying to do. So your wrapper function would accept a component and act as a “proxy” for the real component by returning a component that can intercept the props of the component your function was passed.

Comment: @NickParsons Thanks for your idea, I could implement by HOC. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There would be better way, but I resolved by using HOC which gets all props

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import House from "./House";

// HOC for detecting all props
const withPropsLogging = (Component) => {
  return (props) => {
    console.log(props);
    return <Component {...props} />;
  };
};

const HouseWithPropsLogging = withPropsLogging(House);

const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (count === 2) return;
    setTimeout(() => {
      setCount(count + 1);
    }, 1000);
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <HouseWithPropsLogging count={count} text={text} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```